# Unable to convert bitmap to string then back to bitmap using BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I'm base64 encoding a bitmap to a string in order to send it as part of a JSON object. The recipient of the image will get the string and convert it to an image again.

If this is at all relevant, I'm doing this for an Android app.

Converting the bitmap to a string seems to work ok, but when converting the string back to a bitmap I'm getting a NullPointerException.

I've tried to boil this down to the basics (and converting to a string and back to a bitmap in the same method for testing), so I have the following:

```
public static void convertBitmapToBase64String(Context context, String filename, int maxStringSize)
{
    Bitmap originalBmp = PicUtils.getBitmapFromFilename(filename, null, -1);
    String base64Image = PicUtils.convertBitmapToBase64StringFromFile(context, TEMP_FILENAME);

    // The encoded string is not null, so encoding seems to work.
    DataUtils.log("base64Image length is " + base64Image.length());

    // Test if we can convert back
    final byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);

    // This returns null! Is failing here.
    Bitmap decodedByteBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromFilename(String filename)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
    Bitmap finalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
    return finalBitmap;
}

public static String convertBitmapToBase64StringFromFile(Context context, String filename)
{
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream outputStream = new Base64OutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, Base64.DEFAULT);
        IOUtils.copy(fis, outputStream);
        return new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        DataUtils.log(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: You create `base64EncodedImg`, then ignore it. Everything else is based off of a `base64Image` that does not exist.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, sorry, that was a copy/paste error when I was cleaning the code a bit to paste here. I've updated the variable. I appreciate your help

Comment: I am somewhat skeptical that `new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),"UTF-8")` and `Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT)` are inverse operations. See if the resulting `byte[]` after `decode()` has the same length and contents as does your original.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link I used to solve my problem. I hope this will work for you too.

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-convert-string-to-bitmap-and.html.